# Error trying to connect SQL database with Xamarin using modile data

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, amazon-rds

I can't connect my Xamarin application to SQL database(Amazon RDS) with mobile data.
If I try to connect to SQL database using Wi-Fi, it works.

When I try with mobile data, I get this error:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
  at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync (MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection connection, System.Int32 startTickCount, MySqlConnector.Core.ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.IOBehavior ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002fb] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:437 
  at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync (MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection connection, System.String logMessage, System.Int32 startTickCount, MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.IOBehavior ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000bc] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:367 
  at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync (MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection connection, System.Int32 startTickCount, MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.IOBehavior ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00519] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:94 
  at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync (MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection connection, System.Int32 startTickCount, MySqlConnector.Protocol.Serialization.IOBehavior ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00767] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:124 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync (MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool pool, System.Int32 startTickCount, System.Nullable`1[T] ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00120] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:919 
  at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync (MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool pool, System.Int32 startTickCount, System.Nullable`1[T] ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002f6] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:941 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync (System.Nullable`1[T] ioBehavior, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001c7] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:425 
  at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x00000] in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:373
```

This is my Server string:

```
"Server=xxx;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Password=xxx.;Convert Zero Datetime=True;"
```

Why the connection works only using Wi-Fi connection and doesn't work using mobile data?

Comment: is your db hosted on your local network, or on a publicly accessible server?

Comment: Also are you trying to connect to your SQL Server directly from your Phone?

Comment: My Db is on a publicly accessible server

Comment: I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server directly from my Phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Amazon RDS as host.
The solution was edit the outbound role of db group security and set the IP: 0.0.0.0/0 in order to accept all IP.